# Form with multiple buttons

Tags: java, javascript, html, forms

I am having a form with a submit button and a input button. I want to send a parameter to servlet on form submission.

```
<form action="postValues">
  <table>....</table>
  <input type="submit" name"event" value="add"/>
  <input type="button" name="event" value="refresh" onclick="getValues()"/>
</form>
```

When I click on submit in servlet I am getting "event" value in request parameter but on clicking refresh in servlet I am not getting the value for "event" in refresh parameter. I need that javascript function "getValues", where I need to get the values of table cells.

How can I send the parameter to servlet when this input type is button?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. I don't see why you expect anything to be sent to the server when clicking the `refresh` button, since that should not even submit the form. Please try to explain differently.

Comment: It sounds like he's asking how to send values to the server from the `getValues` function, which is called when `refresh` is clicked.

Comment: Show us the code of getValues(). We don't know what it does and how is does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the "refresh" button then the "getValues()" javascript function is responsible to communicate the server it will not submit the form. so, you need to send the button value separately. you can try this,

```
<input type="button" name="event" value="refresh" onclick="getValues(this)"/>
```

so in the getValues function you'll get this event button reference, so you can send the value of button on query string.

eg:

```
function getValues(button){
    var buttonValue = button.value;
    //send this value in your query string.
}
```